# SQL Left Join not return ALL values from table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve something like this:

Report_Code 325 10  Report_line_text $100

Report_Code 326 20  Report_line_text NULL

Report_Code 327 30  Report_line_text $300

Instead I get this:

Report_Code 325 10  Report_line_text $100

Report_Code 327 30  Report_line_text $300

By using this code:

```
SELECT   PR.RPT_CD 
    ,PR.BR_ID
    ,PR.RPT_LN_SEQ_NUM
    ,PR.RPT_LN_TXT
    ,RS.RSLT_AMT
FROM table 1 RS
  LEFT JOIN table 2 PR
  ON PR.BR_ID = RS.BR_ID
  AND RS.RPT_CD = PR.RPT_CD
WHERE RS.RPT_CD = @REPORT
  AND YR_NUM = @CONTRACT_YR
  AND QTR_NUM = @QTR
  AND PG_CD = @PG_CD
  AND CTRL_CD IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
ORDER BY PR.RPT_LN_SEQ_NUM
```

Why is row 2 from the left join dropping off?  I need to see the NULL row value for Row 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Are any of `YR_NUM`, `QTR_NUM`, `PG_CD` or `CTRL_CD` in table 2?

Comment: Try swapping the first On condition. seems like the RS table should come before the PR table normally.

Comment: @KHeaney The order in the equality condition makes no difference.

Comment: Well at a guess one of your conditions on data you haven't shown us is stripping it out. This is going to be a doh moment, start by chopping there where clause down see if it 'magically appears in teh result set.

Comment: What is the value of RPT_CD in the row that is being dropped? What table are the other columns in that are referenced in your where predicates? Most likely the row is not returned because it doesn't match one of those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any WHERE condition applied to LEFT JOINed table (PR in this case) then the join will be effectively converted to INNER JOIN - as that WHERE condition rules out all non-existent PR rows obviously.

Comment: To be a little more precise: the NULL valued rows created by the outer join would be filtered out by any combination of predicates in the `WHERE` clause which **require a column from the outer joined table to be non-NULL**. (And given that OP query has **unqualified** column references, from the statement, we can't tell which columns are from which table.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows from `PR` returned, along with matching rows from `RS`, you've got your outer join switched around backwards.

If you say:

```
rs LEFT JOIN pr
```

That returns all rows from `rs`, along with matching rows from `pr`. Any rows in `rs` that don't have a matching row in `pr` will also be returned, with dummy row of NULL values for the missing `pr` row.

To get all rows from `pr` returned, you need to swap that around, and put `pr` on the "left" side of the join

```
pr LEFT JOIN rs
```

Then all the rows from `pr` will be returned, even when no matching row is found in `rs`.

---

A few other notes:

Please qualify **all** column references with a table name or preferably a short alias. Some of the column references in your query are qualified, but some of the column references in the WHERE clause are not; so we, the poor readers, can't tell from the statement whether `CTRL_CD` refers to a column in `RS` or `PR`. (And if this is in the context of a procedure, we can't really even know that those are references to columns, and not procedure variables. Get in the habit of qualifying **all** column references, for the sake of the sanity of the soul who comes along behind you and has to decipher the SQL; making your SQL easier to read means it will *cost less* for the business to maintain the code.

If the problem isn't that the join is swapped around backwards, then the most likely problem is that a predicate in the `WHERE` clause is tantamount to specifying an IS NOT NULL condition on a column from the `PR` table, and that will effectively negate the "outerness" of the join. In that case, just relocate that predicate from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.